# Android studio E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have tried every solution I found on-line and anywhere. But I still can't solve this problem. It keeps giving me this error "E/`RecyclerView`: No adapter attached; skipping layout". I tried to use breakpoint to test each code. From the result, I get that data is successfully retrieved from `firebase` and save in `ArrayList` and the size of `mItems` is correct. But this is the result I get.Please somebody help me.

The Result I get

[image: image1]

My firebase structure

[image: image2]

**ShowBookedSlotActivity.java**

```
        public class ShowBookedSlotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG ="Show Booked Activity" ;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
        private FirebaseAuth auth;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_booked_slot);
            setTitle("Booked Gym Slot");
            Log.d(TAG, "on create");

            //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new ListBookedSlotFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("UID", auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                        .commit();
            }



        }



        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            startActivity(new Intent(ShowBookedSlotActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    }
```

**ListBookedSlotFragment.java**

```
      public class ListBookedSlotFragment extends Fragment {
        private final String TAG = "ListBookedSlotFragment";
        private ArrayList<BookedSlot> mItems;
        private ArrayList<String> mItemsKey;
        private RecyclerView mItemRecyclerView;
        private ItemAdapter mAdapter;
        private DatabaseReference mItemRef;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
        private String UID;
        private Query mBookedSlotQuery;
        private DatabaseReference mBookedSlotRef;
        private ValueEventListener mBookedSlotQueryVEL;


        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            UID = this.getArguments().getString("UID");
            Log.d(TAG, "UID: " + UID);


            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            mItems = new ArrayList<>();


            if (UID != null) {
                mItemsKey = new ArrayList<>();
                mBookedSlotQuery = mDatabase.child("booked_slot").orderByChild("UserID").equalTo(UID);
                Log.d(TAG, "mItemRef:" + mBookedSlotQuery);
                mBookedSlotQueryVEL = mBookedSlotQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mItems.clear();
                        mItemsKey.clear();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
                        for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            BookedSlot bookedSlot = d.getValue(BookedSlot.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "bookedSlot:" + bookedSlot.getUserID());
                            mItems.add(bookedSlot);
                            mItemsKey.add(d.getKey());
                        }
                       updateUI();
                     /* TextView infoTextTextview = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.info_text); //show_booked_slot.xml
                        if (mItems.isEmpty()) {
                            infoTextTextview.setText(R.string.Empty);
                        } else {
                          //  infoTextTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            infoTextTextview.setText("Size: ".concat(Integer.toString(mItems.size())));
                        }*/
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "show booked slot databaseError: " + databaseError);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "UID: "+UID);
            }

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
          //  if (mBookedSlotQuery != null) mBookedSlotRef.removeEventListener(mBookedSlotQueryVEL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
           // if (mBookedSlotQuery != null) mBookedSlotRef.removeEventListener(mBookedSlotQueryVEL);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_booked_slot, container, false);
            mItemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view); //in fragment_list_item_booked_slot.xml
            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mItemRecyclerView.getContext(), new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()).getOrientation());
            mItemRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            mItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            return view;
        }


        private void updateUI() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enter updateUI(); mItems: " + mItems);
            mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItems);
            mItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            BookedSlot mItems;
            TextView mNameTextView;
            TextView mDateTextView;
            TextView mTimeTextView;

            ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                //refer list_booked_gym_slot.xml
                mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
                mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);
                mTimeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_time);

              if (UID != null) {
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "UID != null");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                            builder
                                    .setMessage("Delete This Slot?")
                                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            deleteSlot(mItems);
                                        }
                                    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // User cancelled the dialog
                                }
                            });

                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            void bindData(BookedSlot s){
                mItems = s;
                mNameTextView.setText(s.getUsername());
                mDateTextView.setText(s.getBookedDate());
                mTimeTextView.setText(s.getBookedTime());
            }

        }


        private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder>{
            private ArrayList<BookedSlot> mItems;

            ItemAdapter(ArrayList<BookedSlot> Items){
                this.mItems = Items;
            }

            @Override
            public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_booked_gym_slot,parent,false);
                return new ItemHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
                BookedSlot s = mItems.get(position);
                holder.bindData(s);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mItems.size();
            }
        }

        private void deleteSlot(final BookedSlot itemClicked) {
            mDatabase.child("booked_slot").child(UID).child(mItemsKey.get(mItems.indexOf(itemClicked))).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if(databaseError == null){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), itemClicked.getBookedDate() + "  " + itemClicked.getBookedTime() +" Slot Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**ShowBookedSlotActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.jaseline.myfyp.ShowBookedSlotActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jaseline.myfyp.ShowBookedSlotActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_show_booked_slot">

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_list_booked_slot.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**list_booked_slot.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: context missing in layout, showin too

Comment: where should I add the context?

Comment: When using `onCreate()` fragment method, you can assign variables, get Intent extras, and anything else that doesn't involve the View hierarchy. For further understanding, you need to read about lifecycle in android. In any case, add all `onCreate()` statements in either your `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: you can try **mItemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);**

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jaseline.myfyp.ShowBookedSlotActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_show_booked_slot"> , this is wrong it should be used in the new Recycler view layout, simply put ur recycler view there

Answer (score 0):

The `Fragment` Life Cycle is as follows :

```
1. constructor
2. onAttach
3. onCreate
4. onCreateView
```

So you cant call `updateUI()` method to set data to `RecyclerView` before setting `LayoutManager`.
Only after setting `LayoutManager` should you give data to `RecyclerView`

Comment: I understand your point. Can you point me with some sample code please?

Comment: Take all of your code inside onCreate() and put it inside onCreateView() just before return View.